# Amazon OpenSearch (ElasticSearch) Piped Processing Language, "where" command - How to Filter for "some_field is not null"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

I am building a Notebook in AWS OpenSearch (formerly Amazon elasticsearch) and I want to provide a condition to the "where" command excluding documents where a particular field is not null.

In SQL this would simply be "where my_field is not null" however, The notebook indicates a syntax error where this condition is added to the where command.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
where length(my_field)>0
```

From Open Distro for Elasticsearch function docs [here](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/ppl/functions/) and [here](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/sql/functions/).